# usmaps.js Event binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to figure out this bit of code but I cant.  I have tried numerous times to decipher this.  Can someone help me out.

```
    $('#map').usmap({
  <event>State: {
    'MD' : function(event, data) {
      console.log('You interacted with the state of Maryland');
    }
  }
});
```

I would like this to be a click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up accomplishing it like this

```
click: function(event, data) {
        if(data.name == "AK" || data.name == "AL" || data.name == "OR" || data.name == "CO" || data.name == "WA"){
            $('#clicked-state').text("Marijuana is legalized for recreational use for those over the age of 21 in " + data.name);
        }
        else if(data.name == "CA" || data.name == "NV" || data.name == "MT" || data.name == "AZ" || data.name == "MN" || data.name == "IL" || data.name == "MI" || data.name == "NY" || data.name == "VT" || data.name == "NH" || data.name == "ME" || data.name == "MA" || data.name == "CT" || data.name == "NJ" || data.name == "MD" || data.name == "DE" || data.name == "RI" || data.name == "DC"){
            $('#clicked-state').text("Medical marijuana is legalized in " + data.name);
        }
        else{
            $('#clicked-state').text("Marijuana is illegal in " + data.name);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentaiton show this:

```
$('#map').usmap({
  // The click action
  click: function(event, data) {
    $('#clicked-state')
      .text('You clicked: '+data.name)
      .parent().effect('highlight', {color: '#C7F464'}, 2000);
  }
});
```

Did you try like that?

**EDIT:**

```
$('#map').usmap({
  clickState: {
    'NY' : function(event, data) {
      console.log('You interacted with the state of Maryland');
    }
  }
});
```

This way you will be able to click only on a state.

Comment: Yes and I am doing that for something else.  The problem is I am trying to do specific states

Comment: You want 2 differents cilck events?

Comment: So I need a state specific click event that is all.  So all 50 states could say something different when you click on them.  Does that makes sense?

Comment: Thank you ... I think that might work and appreciate the help.  Check out the way I accomplished it above.